# TabBar with boolean

Tags: flutter, tabs, boolean, tabbar

I heve created TabBar with 2 tabs. And I equated them to a boolean. For example, if the first tab is `true`, the second tab is `false`. And view is exchanged when the value is true.
I want to create TabBar with 3 tabs. Is it possible to do this with a boolean?  For exmaple :

```
true , false , false
```

or

```
false , true , false
```

or

```
false , false , true
```

How is it possible to get value in such a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Flutter have it's own TabBar class where you can use it in your scenario. I add 2 link below for you

1. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs
2. https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-tabbar-and-tricks-4f36e06025a4

Good Luck:D

Comment: Thanks @TryHarder. But I am using TabBar for a website. NavigationRail was also used on the site. I could not use TabBar and NavigationRail together :(